# Update itemsource of a DataGridComboBoxColumn depending on another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm using a Datagrid with 2 DataGridComboBoxColumns and I'm trying to update the itemsource of the second column depending on the selected 'league' in the first column.

My xaml:

```
            <DataGrid Name="DataTable" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="DataTableLeague" Header="League"  DisplayMemberPath="League.Name" SelectedValuePath="League.Name" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding LeagueName}">
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="CmbLeague_SelectionChanged" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="DataTableClub" Header="Club" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ClubName}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

code behind:

```
public Editor()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
      DataTableLeague.ItemsSource = Leagues;         
}

private void CmbLeague_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ???
}
```

`List<League> Leagues` contains `List<Clubs>` and should only be used as a source. The selection is stored in an ObservableCollection named Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling an event, you could bind the `ItemsSource` of the second `ComboBox` to a source property of your data object and set it in the setter of the `LeagueName` property which is bound to the selected value of the first `ComboBox`.

Make sure that your data object implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications whenever the you set the source property for the `ItemsSource` property of the second `ComboBox`, e.g.:

```
public class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _leagueName;
    public string LeagueName
    {
        get { return _leagueName; }
        set 
        { 
            _leagueName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();

            Teams = ...;
        }
    }


    private IEnumerable<Team> _teams;
    public IEnumerable<Team> Teams
    {
        get { return _teams; }
        set { _teams = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

**XAML:**

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="DataTableClub" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" ... />
```

Comment: while this seems to be a solid approach, i would like to see a solution using the `CmbLeague_SelectionChanged` event

Answer (score 1):

> while [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69090446/7252182) seems to be a solid approach, i would like to see a solution using the `CmbLeague_SelectionChanged` event

Well, you could cast the `DataContext` of the `ComboBox` that gets passed to the event handler and then set the property:

```
private void CmbLeague_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
    if (cmb.DataContext is DataItem dataItem)
    {
        dataItem.Teams = ...;
    }
}
```

You will still need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your data class though.